# Why dft sine plot is so strange

Tags: discrete-signals, dft

Why does my dft plot of $\sin(x)$ look so strange? It goes to negative and then inverts closer to the edge.

```
x=0:0.1:10;
N=max(size(x));
y=sin(x);
plot(fftshift(real(fft(y)/N)));
```

[image]

Comment: imho you need to change `real` to `abs`

Comment: i tried it helped fix the part of negative interval but that doesn't make any change to the peak:
https://imgur.com/a/b9vFRWt

Comment: it is need tapering beginning and end of the signal or make integer value for number of periods, https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/windows.html

Comment: thank you! i think i get the idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things you can try, depending on what you're aiming for.

If you want to see a sharp peak at frequency $\omega = 1$, as in the code in your question, then you need to increase the DFT resolution by increasing the number of samples in the signal. With `x = 0:0.1:100`, I get:

[image]

If you want to see a sharp peak without increasing the number of samples, you need to increase the signal's frequency. With `y = sin(10*x)` I get:

[image]

Note that in both cases what has been done is to increase the number of sine periods in the signal `y`. This is the key to obtaining a high-resolution spectrum using the DFT.

Other relevant concepts that are involved here are "spectral leakage" and "windowing". See [Why does spectral leakage arise in an FFT?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/10120/11256) and [What should be considered when selecting a windowing function when smoothing a time series?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/208/11256) to learn more.